# Custom layout on iOS 7 renders element to high

Tags: layout, view, ios7

I have a problem with custom layout on iOS 7. Everything appears  too high, i.e. under the navigation bar. On iOS 6 it works like a charm even when compiled with iOS 7 SDK.

Below I post code used to init and layout the view. I don't use Interface Builder and I would prefer not to. Any help appreciated.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.documentTitle = [UITextField new];
        self.documentExtension = [UILabel new];

        self.documentTitle.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Document title"];
        self.documentTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize] + 1];
        self.documentTitle.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        self.documentTitle.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        self.documentTitle.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        self.documentTitle.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;

        self.documentExtension.text = @".pdf";
        self.documentExtension.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [self addSubview:self.documentTitle];
        [self addSubview:self.documentExtension];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 10, 12, 10);
    CGRect layoutRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, padding);
    CGPoint p = layoutRect.origin;

    CGSize tmpSize;
    CGFloat tfSpaceHorizontal = 6;
    CGFloat tfSpaceVertical = 6;

    CGSize tmpSizeDocumentExtension = [self.documentExtension sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(layoutRect), 1000)];

    tmpSize = CGSizeMake(
            roundf((CGRectGetWidth(layoutRect) - tfSpaceHorizontal - tmpSizeDocumentExtension.width)),
            32
    );

    self.documentTitle.frame = CGRectMake(
            p.x, p.y,
            tmpSize.width,
            tmpSize.height
    );

    p.x += tmpSize.width + tfSpaceHorizontal;
    CGFloat addedHeight = roundf(tmpSize.height/2 - tmpSizeDocumentExtension.height/2);
    addedHeight = addedHeight > 0 ? addedHeight : 0;
    p.y += addedHeight;

    self.documentExtension.frame = CGRectMake(
            p.x,
            p.y,
            tmpSizeDocumentExtension.width,
            tmpSizeDocumentExtension.height
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 7, every view controller uses full-screen layout, so the coordinate system starts under the status bar, so mind that while positioning your views.

This is mentioned in Apple's [iOS 7 UI Transitioning Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1).